# How to combine SqlAlchemy query with ilke and string formating?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying  to make an ilike query on a PostgreSQL database:

```
conn.execute('select geocodigo, nome, GEOJSON from "Dengue_global"."Municipio" where nome' " ilike('{}%')".format(m[:4]))
```

where `m[:4]` is the substring I am trying to match.

I am getting the following Exception:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-72ff2adae1f7> in <module>
      5     except Exception:
      6         print(m)
----> 7         res = conn.execute('select geocodigo, nome, GEOJSON from "Dengue_global"."Municipio" where nome' r" ilike('{}%')".format(m[:4]))
      8     gj = res.fetchone()
      9     if gj is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in execute(self, object_, *multiparams, **params)
    972         """
    973         if isinstance(object_, util.string_types[0]):
--> 974             return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)
    975         try:
    976             meth = object_._execute_on_connection

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_text(self, statement, multiparams, params)
   1145             parameters,
   1146             statement,
-> 1147             parameters,
   1148         )
   1149         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1238         except BaseException as e:
   1239             self._handle_dbapi_exception(
-> 1240                 e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
   1241             )
   1242 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1458                 util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
   1459             else:
-> 1460                 util.reraise(*exc_info)
   1461 
   1462         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in reraise(tp, value, tb, cause)
    275         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    276             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 277         raise value
    278 
    279 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1234                 if not evt_handled:
   1235                     self.dialect.do_execute(
-> 1236                         cursor, statement, parameters, context
   1237                     )
   1238         except BaseException as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    534 
    535     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 536         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    537 
    538     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing
```

If I remove the `%` symbol from the query the exception goes away, but my match does not work.

Any Ideas about what can be causing this and how to work around this and have my query work?

===== **Solution** =====

```
from sqlalchemy import text
conn.execute(atext('select geocodigo, nome, GEOJSON from "Dengue_global"."Municipio" where nome' " ilike(:search ||'%')"),
                      {'search': m[:4]})
```

Comment: Please don't use string formatting for passing parameters to SQL queries.

Comment: In your other answer, you forgot to explain why you should encapsulate the query string  as a text() object. And forgot to mention that text() comes from SqlAlchemy, which I figured out. After that it worked. thanks.